# Asus P6X58-E WS motherboard memory limits

Tags: memory, motherboard, memory-limit

I've just ordered motherboard Asus P6X58-E WS, and now I'm, looking for memory for it.

It has 6 slots, but the strange thing is, that in [specifications it says that it is limited to 24G of memory](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1366/P6X58E_WS/#specifications) .
I'm planning on using 8G Kingston KVR1333D3D4R9S/8G sticks with it. Using those sticks, I'll be teoretically limited to 48G. Does the 24G limitation mean, that even if I install all 6 sticks, I still will be limited by 24G of possible memory?
Sorry if the question seems dumb, but I never faced such a limitation before

Comment: Have you verified that it can accept 8GB modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with memory. Once I've installed non-buffered ecc, the system booted and started to work

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very late answer, but I figured maybe it'd help anyone out that has the same question and stumbles upon this via Google. I have the P6X58-E WS, and it can do maximum 4 gigs per slot.

I bought an 8gb stick thinking the same thing you were, but the board wouldn't post until I downgraded to 4gb sticks. Asking the same question on a different forum confirmed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no clear answer... 
Asus P6X58-E WS based on Intel X58 chipset where memory controller removed (as it exists in Intel Core i7 CPUs). So maximum memory supported by this MB depends from CPU model - some of them supports up to 32Gb but in 2 ch config, some - 24Gb in 3ch config. Check your CPU specification for more details...

Comment: It supports xeon x5600 series, which I plan on using, and the memory limit for those processors is 288G, so no worries there